# Is it possible to export a function that calls another function defined in the file where the module is imported from?

Tags: javascript, function, import, export, es6-modules

Example:

```
// module "my-module.js"    
export default function func1() {
      ...
      func2();
      ...
    }
```

where func2 is only available in the file where we do:

```
import func1 from './my-module.js'

function func2() {
  console.log('OK');
}

func1();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This seems like a scenario where you might want to make use of making an abstract class that has a declared but not defined `func2()` which `func1()` would call. Export the class entirely, and in the file importing it, implement the abstract class and add definition for `func2()`, then `func1()` would work here as intended.

Comment: That also seems to be a good option, @BinHong, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `func2` must be defined when you create a `func1`, otherwise it will be `undefined` and will throw a runtime exception when `func1` will be invoked.

You can pass `func2` as an argument of `func1` and invoke it inside.

```js
// module "my-module.js"
export default function func1(callback) {
  callback();
}
```

```js
import func1 from './my-module.js';

function func2() {
  console.log('OK');
}

func1(func2);
```